# Symfony2.3 setting value and innerHTML of a choicefield from a query

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, choicefield

**From a query I'm trying to personalize the choice field.**

this is how I get the content of the select:

```
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $query2 = $em->createQuery("SELECT p.id,p.nombre FROM Exppromociones p");
    $productos = $query2->getArrayResult();
```

The table should look like this:

```
{"id":93,"nombre":"Bucket"},
{"id":152,"nombre":"Spoon"},
{"id":142,"nombre":"Fork"}
```

With the variable $productos I build a form:

```
   $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->add('productos', 'choice', array('label' => 'Productos',
            'required' => true,
            'choices' => $productos,
        ))
        ->getForm();
```

And that form results to:

```
<optgroup label="0">
   <option value="id">93</option>
   <option value="nombre">Bucket</option>
</optgroup>
```

I want the choices field to have the value equal to the id and the innerHTML equal to nombre, like this:

```
<option value=93>Bucket</option>
```

Comment: Property `choice_label` will help you.

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#example-usage

Comment: @u_mulder Symfony2 doesn't have `choice_label`

Comment: Symfony 2 have choice_label : https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/reference/forms/types/choice.html

Comment: It has one but it won't do you any good for this problem.  Just need to adjust your array per the example in the docs.

Comment: Sorry, I feel really dumb right now, it's Symfony 2.3, I'm really new to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I kept the same query

```
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $query2 = $em->createQuery("SELECT p.id,p.nombre FROM Exppromociones p");
    $productos = $query2->getArrayResult();
```

but before creating my form builder I initialize an array, extract the id and nombre from "$productos" and load them into $choices

```
        $choices=array();
        foreach ($categorias as $cat){
            $id=$cat['id'];
            $nombre=$cat['nombre'];
            $choices[$id] = $nombre;
        }
        $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->add('categoria', 'choice', array('label' => 'Categoria',
            'required' => true,
            'choices' => $choices, 
        ))
        ->getForm();
```

Now my options look like this

```
<option value=93>Bucket</option>
```